# Lowering the throttling temperature in Windows 8 for a laptop

Tags: windows-8, cpu, cpu-temperature, cpu-throttling

I've seen a lot of posts about disabling the throttling temperatures but none regarding setting them.

I have an Acer V17 Nitro, i7 laptop and it's CPU temperature reaches 95°C before throttling. It's a very powerful laptop, crippled by a bad cooling system. I already undervolted by 70mV and disabled hyper boost.

Currently, I have to go into Power Options and adjust Maximum CPU Frequency between 40% and 80% to keep the temperatures under 80°C. But this depends on the application. And I have to do this manually for each application I'm using.

Ironically, some applications (especially Fortnite) will run just fine with the CPU frequency set to 30-40% with the temperatures only rising to 80°C, while others will run at the same temperatures with the maximum frequency set to 80%. It just depends on how the code was written and how many cores are being used.

I know the throttling temperature is set to 95°C for the CPU, but even if it doesn't melt the CPU, it can cause a lot of other issues, like melting the case.

I would prefer to lower the throttling temperature to something like 80°C. This way I don't have to adjust the maximum CPU frequency by hand every time.

Is there a way to do this from the BIOS? From Windows? Via a third party app?

Comment: So someone edited my post like crazy but nobody has an answer. ?!

Comment: Someone took the time to make your question much easier to read, making it more likely that someone will see your question and be able to provide a good answer. Posting the same question again will just result in it being closed as a duplicate of this one.